# Explanation for why this condition '' && false would return ''

Tags: javascript

I am a bit confused with this condition:

```
 console.log('' && false) //''
```

I was expecting it to return false, however it returns `''`

but with empty space, it's returning false

```
 console.log(' ' && false) //true
```

Could someone please explain the reason for this?

Comment: zero length string is falsey, non-zero length string is truthy.

Comment: @squint thanks mate but why it return '' rather than boolean with that line

Comment: Because `&&` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) the first value if it's false-y, or the second value otherwise.

Comment: @Bruce - Because `&&` short-circuits if the first value is falesy. In other words, `''` is falsey, so it is returned in the first example. Likewise, `' '` isn't falsey, so `false` is returned in the second example. For a better explanation, see the relevant MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: @Bruce: That's one of those fundamental questions you can have answered by reading documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: *i was expecting to return false* Why would you expect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

So `console.log('' && false) //''`

because `''` can be converted to false (`!!''` will return `false`), it will return `''`

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving out of the first log, '' is not the same condition string. Check this:

```
console.log('' && false || 'else string')
```

And you will see it logs the 'else string'. Since your condition has zero length, it goes after the else which does not exist. So it simply shows an emoty string.

Zero length strings are falsy in general and that's why you get false result out of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

"&&" operator evaluates the first operand and proceeds to next operand only if first operand is evaluated to some truthy value or true itself. This evaluation continues until the complete expression is evaluated.

For example, a==b && b>=7 && c==6. In this, only if a==b is true it checks b>=7 and if this evaluates to true then it checks c==6.

Here in your question, '' is an empty string and is a falsy value. Hence, it didn't proceed for the last operand and returned ''. For more information on truthy and falsy values in javascript go through this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/